Is it possible to find distance between 2 nodes of a generic tree without lowest common ancestor (or path from root)
In case of Binary Trees, It is possible to find the distance between the two nodes without finding the path from the root node or lowest common ancestor.
I was wondering if it is possible in the case of generic trees. As finding Lowest common ancestor is possible in generic as shown in below code.
TreeNode* findLCA(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q) {
    if (!root || root == p || root == q) return root;
    TreeNode* lca = nullptr;
    int count = 0;

    for (auto child : root->children) {
        TreeNode* node = findLCA(child, p, q);
        if (node) {
            count++;
            lca = node;
        }
        if (count == 2) return root;
    }

    return lca;
}

Could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better approach to solve this problem without finding the LCA? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Since you are considering generic trees, you have to think in terms of a connected acyclic graph, then do Uniform-Cost Search from the root node A, and mark down all predecessors leading to node B.

Uniform-Cost Search(UCS) Pathfinding on Trees
If your tree is generic and not necessarily binary, then you are ultimately dealing with a connected forest, hence, an acyclic graph (particularly one that is not necessarily directed). Therefore, you can simply conduct Uniform-Cost Search (a closed-domain variant of the Dijkstra algorithm) by setting either p or q as your start/end nodes.
UCS works just like Dijkstra algorithm but with the strong requirement of locating specific nodes known as goal states. The algorithm halts (and optionally reports the traversed paths) when all goal states are found. The challenge here is trees are unweighted, so all edges would have to be treated equally, introducing some customizations in how edges are processed.
In the worst case, we explore all edges and nodes in the graph without any costly repetitive work (if carefully implemented), and since we are treating all edges equally, a binary heap for prioritizing lowest costs is not needed so a linear time execution can be achieved instead of a log-linear (or linearithmic) runtime. Furthermore, the idea of "cost" is now implied, and no longer relevant - it is only the behavior of the UCS we wish to emulate.

Pseudocode
The following is a breakdown and pseudocode of how a modified UCS algorithm can be executed on a tree being treated as a connected forest and undirected acyclic graph. It is strongly recommended to be well-versed with the inner workings of the UCS at this point, there is already an excellent explanation by prof. John Levine.
I'll be using a design pattern similar to the Active-Records Design Pattern to structure the precedence table for tracing paths.
ALGORITHM: Find Path in Tree

Initialize a queue containing the start state p and initially record default status for all nodes in the tree/graph; preemptively mark p as visited to jump start the execution; V(G) is the graph theory notation convention for the set of all nodes (vertices) in the tree:

queue ← deque([p])
path_table(v) ← Record(predecessor ← None, visited ← False) for all v in V(G)
path_table(p).visited ← True


While loop to search for goal state q:

While queue is not empty:
    current_node ← queue.pop_left()
    If current_node equals q:
        Break loop (Goal found)

         2.1. [Nested under while loop] Expand children of current node:
    For each edge e incident to current_node:
        child ← e.opposite(current_node)
        If path_table(child).visited equals False:
            path_table(child).visited ← True
            path_table(child).predecessor ← current_node
            queue.append(child)


Path reconstruction:

Initialize empty list path_list
current_node ← q
While current_node is not None:
    path_list.append(current_node)
    current_node ← path_table(current_node).predecessor


Return result:
Return (path_table, reverse(path_list))


Implementation Demonstration
I have implemented this algorithm in Python here by utilizing an Adjacency Map graph ADT representing my acyclic, connected, tree-like graph; however, you might have to clone the entire repo to run the code due to some dependency structuring (you'll want to use PyCharm); this verbosity is the exact reason I've opted not to include the code here as it won't fit in properly. So let's explore two examples demonstrating the exact output from the linked implementation instead.
Example 1: Traditional Binary Tree
           S
         /   \
        A     B
             /
            C
           / \
          D   G1
         /
        E
       / \
      F   G2
       \
        G3


Say we start from node p = A, and we want to find a path to node E, the Find Path in Tree algorithm returns the distance records which tells you which nodes were visited upon halting after encountering the goal state q = E:
START :: -> A -> S -> B -> C -> D -> E -> END

Node | Pred | Visited   |
S    |  A   |   True    |
A    |  $   |   True    |
B    |  S   |   True    |
C    |  B   |   True    |
D    |  C   |   True    |
E    |  D   |   True    |
F    |  $   |   False   |
G1   |  C   |   True    |
G2   |  $   |   False   |
G3   |  $   |   False   |

Notice how the algorithm implicitly treated A as the root by denoting its predecessor as a terminal ($)/null node while marking it as visited? This is similar to how the traversal of a BFS, DFS, or Dijkstra execution are called BFS-tree, DFS-tree, and Dijkstra-tree respectively, because each traversal returns a tree that is rooted under the starting node. However, do take note that unvisited nodes (marked as false under the visited column) also have the terminating string as their predecessor. The main difference is the fact that the root is always marked as visited.
For full disclosure, these are the results when you start from node S and select G3 as your goal state:
Can you guess what happens in the distance record?

   All nodes are visited!

START :: -> S -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G3 -> END

Node | Pred | Visited   |
S    |  $   |   True    |
A    |  S   |   True    |
B    |  S   |   True    |
C    |  B   |   True    |
D    |  C   |   True    |
E    |  D   |   True    |
F    |  E   |   True    |
G1   |  C   |   True    |
G2   |  E   |   True    |
G3   |  F   |   True    |

Example 2: Generic Non-Binary Tree
           S
        /  |  \
       A   B   C
      / \    / | \
     D   E  F  G  H
          |     |
          I     J
         / \   /
        K   L M


Just as before, setting p = K and q = F yields the following:
START :: -> K -> I -> E -> A -> S -> C -> F -> END

Node | Pred | Visited   |
S    |  A   |   True    |
A    |  E   |   True    |
B    |  S   |   True    |
C    |  S   |   True    |
D    |  A   |   True    |
E    |  I   |   True    |
F    |  C   |   True    |
G    |  C   |   True    |
H    |  C   |   True    |
I    |  K   |   True    |
J    |  $   |   False   |
K    |  $   |   True    |
L    |  I   |   True    |
M    |  $   |   False   |

